# How does docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile work together?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

From my understanding,
Dockerfile is like the config/recipe for creating the image, while docker-compose is used to easily create multiple containers which may have relationship, and avoid creating the containers by docker command repeatedly.

There are two files.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /server

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 3030

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  test-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test-db
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  test-web:
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=local
      #- DEBUG=*
      - PORT=3030
    image: node:lts-alpine
    build: ./
    command: >
        npm run dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/server
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    depends_on:
      - test-db
```

**Question 1**
When I run docker-compose up --build

a. The image will be built based on Dockerfile
b. What's then?

**Question 2**

```
  test-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
```

```
  test-web:
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=local
      #- DEBUG=*
      - PORT=3030
    image: node:lts-alpine
```

I am downloading the image for dockerhub with above code, but why and when do I need the image created in --build?

**Question 3**

```
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Is this line means that the data is supposed to store at memory in location /var/lib/mysql, while I copy this data in my working directory ./db-data?

**Update**

**Question 4**

```
    build: ./
```

What is this line for?

Comment: Please limit the post to one question. Multiple questions should be posted separately.

Comment: Did you look a bit at the docs in https://docs.docker.com/compose/ ? There are parts explaining the build steps and the volume binding.

Comment: @zigarn yes, I've watched lots of youtube video and doc but still confusing

Answer (score 7):

It is recommended to go through the [Getting Started](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/), most of your questions would be solved.

Let me try to highlight some of those to you.

1. The difference between `Dockerfile` and `Compose file`

   1. [Docker can build images automatically by reading the instructions from a Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)
   2. [Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)
   3. The main difference is `Dockerfile` is used to build an image while `Compose` is to build and run an application.
   4. You have to build an image by `Dockerfile` then run it by `Compose`
2. After you run `docker-compose up --build` the image is built and cached in your system, then Compose would start the containers defined by `docker-compose.yml`
3. If you specify the `image` then it would be download while built if specify the `build: ./`
4. [Volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by and used by Docker containers.](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), Images are read-only, and all editing for a container would be destroyed after it's deleted, so you have to use `Volumes` if you want to persistent data.

Remember, Doc is always your friend.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with a docker image not working and I needed to roll my own.
I still wanted to use compose to deploy it with my other images.

I found my answer here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#illustrative-example

Even if it is a late answer I hope it helps @123123 with question 1.